Selenium WebDriver Quits Unexpectedly on AWS Elastic Beanstalk but Works Locally
I'm encountering an issue with a Flask application that uses Selenium WebDriver to log in to a website using cookies. The application works perfectly on my local test server, but when I deploy it to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, the WebDriver quits unexpectedly without any error message. Instead of taking a screenshot of the page, the driver quits and the program stalls.
The program successfully navigates to the site, adds the cookies I want, but upon a refresh, the the driver seems to stall out.
Note that WEBSITE here is a placeholder.
Code snippet:
 def login(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.get(WEBSITE)
        before_cookies = self.driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
        logging.debug(before_cookies)
        time.sleep(1)

        self.add_cookies()
        after_cookies = self.driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
        logging.debug(after_cookies)
        time.sleep(2)

        self.driver.refresh() #This is where it seems to quit. I don't get the 'refresh_64' screenshot in the log file.
        time.sleep(2)
        refresh_64 = self.driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
        logging.debug(refresh_64)
    

Relevant log file output:
long string (base 64 of 'after_cookies' screenshot) 

2024-07-18 21:17:42,429 DEBUG: POST http://localhost:35951/session/e0e3a47dbdf86bbb8365d1158af73/url {'url': WEBSITE}

Environment details

Local: macOS (Sonoma 14.5)
AWS EB: Amazon Linux 2023
ChromeDriver version 126.0.6478.126
Selenium version: 4.22.0

Thank you!
